# Why are there different version numbers on X.org

Tags: xorg, versions

Some websites say the latest version of X.org is 7.4, some say 11, and some say 1.15.1. These numbers are completely different from each other, yet it's the same version. Can anyone explain which number means what and why when installing drivers it says install on x.org 6.9 or later but after installing it says I have 1.15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are confusing Xorg numbering and the numbering of the modules.

> Xorg version numbering has changed since xorg 7.0. Nowadays, Xorg is released with a version number (like 7.4). This release is composed of various modules which have their own version number (each module started at version "1.0" when Xorg 7.0 development cycle started). For instance, Xorg 7.3 was shipped with Xserver version v1.4, xf86-input-evdev v1.1.5, xf86-video-intel v2.1.1

https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg

and

http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/10/x11r75-released-but-what-is-it.html

If that does not clarify your version numbers, update your question with version of Ubuntu and the specific packages you are asking about.